# Xcode storyboard screen type affecting layout within simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, simulator

In developing an app on Xcode, I have an issue where alignment of certain labels/image views is only correct on the simulator when the 'View as:' option in the storyboard matches the same device type.

I am creating an app which contains a square near the middle of the screen (an image view) and within it, a bunch of smaller image views arranged in a a circle.

If I go to the storyboard and view the screen as a particular device (i.e iPhone Xs), when I run the same device on the simulator (also iPhone Xs), all is perfectly aligned. If I then go back to the storyboard viewing the screen as an alternate device (i.e. iPhone 8), and rerun the simulator (still iPhone Xs), the alignments are off.

The square (which is done using autolayout in the storyboard) looks fine throughout, whereas the smaller image views, which are created in code on the fly, are the ones that are awry. Their positions are based on the centre of the square, which is calculated as self.squareView.center.x and self.squareView.center.y. These calculations seem to be based on what screen is in the storyboard, and not the screen in the simulator.

Has anyone had any issues with similar or know how this could be resolved?

Code below:

```
let radius = 1.4 // these will be arranged in a circle within the square view.
let angleStep = Float(2.0 * Double.pi) / Double(arrayOfImages.count) // arrayOfImages.count will be a number between 5 and 7.
let yPos: Float = cosf(angleStep * radius)
let xPos: Float = sinf(angleStep * radius)

// The below is to determine the midpoint of the view that I am having the issue with:

let setCenter = CGPoint(x: self.squareView.center.x + CGFloat(xPos), y: self.squareView.center.y + CGFloat(yPos)


// Then the code to arrange the image view:

arrayOfImages[i].frame = CGRect(x:CGFloat(xPos), y:CGFloat(yPos), width: 30, height: 30)
arrayOfImages[i].center = setCenter
```

I'm not quite sure the bottom two lines of code are quite right.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem where the simulator needs to match the storyboard device display to work correctly.

I think I've resolved my issues by getting the bounds for a view during the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method in my view controller.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let setCenter = CGPoint(x: self.squareView.center.x + CGFloat(xPos), y: 
    self.squareView.center.y + CGFloat(yPos)

    arrayOfImages[i].frame = CGRect(x:CGFloat(xPos), y:CGFloat(yPos), width: 30, height: 30)
    arrayOfImages[i].center = setCenter
  }
```

It seems the height and width value of the squareView you are referencing may not be accurate until this part in the lifecycle.